# Broadcom Corp. BCM4313 Wirelss not detected in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom

I update my Toshiba PORTÉGÉ from Precise(12.04) to Quantal (12.10). After update to Precise wireless device works fine. But after update wireless device is not detect on network manager.

The `lspci` command says:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN 
    Controller [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
            Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. Device [144f:7175]
            Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
            Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
            Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
            Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 3
            Region 0: Memory at d4500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
            Capabilities: <access denied>
            Kernel modules: bcma
```

The ethernet connection works fine. I try to install `firmware-b43-installer` but it says:

```
$ sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
...
Unsuported device(s) found: PCI id 14e4:4727
Aborting
```

More info related gived by `lshw`:

```
    root@caprica:~# sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: 82577LC Gigabit Network Connection
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 19
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
       nombre lógico: eth0
       versión: 06
       serie: e8:9d:87:ed:f4:2a
       tamaño: 1Gbit/s
       capacidad: 1Gbit/s
       anchura: 32 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.0.0-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-6 ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       recursos: irq:41 memoria:d4700000-d471ffff memoria:d472a000-d472afff ioport:3020(size=32)
  *-network NO RECLAMADO
       descripción: Network controller
       producto: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       fabricante: Broadcom Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       versión: 01
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuración: latency=0
       recursos: memoria:d4500000-d4503fff
```

I execute this too and this is the output:

```
root@caprica:~# rfkill list all
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have checking the model in http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43:

```
BCM4313 - chipset uses unsupported LCN PHY, we work on it
```

I had configured privated drivers in the visual enviroment, Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from `bcmwl-kernel-source` but don't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe bcmwl-kernel-source is correct for your device. Let's try again:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

You should be all set.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but it doesn't work. 
I reinstall the bcmwl-kernel-source but no wireless module is founded: 
`sergio@caprica:~$ sudo modprobe wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for wl
`

Comment: Please try my edited commands above.

Comment: For the 3.8 kernel now with 12.04.3 this will fail to compile. See http://askubuntu.com/a/337999/88802 for the workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

On the upgrade from 12.x to 13.04, the old bcm43 module got blacklisted, however on my mac-mini, the b43 (free driver) was already blacklisted.

Especially for people having used the non free driver in 12.x, this becomes a problem, as the b43 is also blacklisted under 12.x there. So - we have 2 bcm43 and b43 both blacklisted, and none will work. So - check the /etc/modprobe.d directory for any b43 and bcm43 entries, and make sure only one gets blacklists.

YYMV - but I found the bcm43 non free to provide better performance