# Why my roommates' connection to the Internet is lost, when I'm connected to our router on Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, connection, 13.10

We have 4 computers in our flat. When I'm starting to use Ubuntu and when I'm connected to our network, at least one of them has connection problems, that is, their connection status says that everything is fine, but they can't, for example, explore the Internet or play online games. Nothing like that happens when I'm using Windows. How to fix it? My Ubuntu version is 13.10

Comment: What is your wireless card?

Comment: Could it be unproper ip-setup? Check to see that you haven't got the same ip-adresses. (in win run cmd.exe and write ipconfig, in ubuntu check connection information in the top right corner) Just a thought...

Comment: IP are different. Any other thoughts?

And my wireless card is Broadcom 802.11n, built-in on my laptop

Comment: Some Broadcom cards cause such problems because the faulty proprietary driver is causing them to push too much power into the air, which temporarily deafens other devices http://askubuntu.com/questions/277064

Comment: Please run the terminal command: lspci -nn -d 14e4:  Is your device by chance 14e4:4727?? It can be fixed.

Comment: @chili555

Yes, it is. So what should I do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.04, I believe the default bcmwl-kernel-source will not work correctly for your Broadcom 4313. I recommend that you get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb
```

Or, if yours is a 32-bit system:

```
wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_5.100.82.112+bdcom-0ubuntu3_i386.deb
```

Confirm 32- or 64-bit:

```
arch
```

Then do:

```
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Reboot and give us your report.

Comment: Wow, man. How'd you guys figured it all out? I tried to google my problem and tips I saw there wasn't as specific and as accurate as yours. It's alright by now, my friends aren't experiencing any problems, neither am I. Really, really thanks. If anything bad will happen, I'll let you know.

Comment: A decade of study and I'm starting to get the hang of it! Glad it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check to see if your Ubuntu box is running a DHCP server?

It may be trying to act as a router.

Try this:

```
sudo ps -ef | grep dhcp
```

and if it returns anything, you might want to kill that process.

Post the results and I can help further.

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: I updated the answer with what I would do.

Comment: It returned the following:
root      1717  1309  0 23:15 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -d -sf /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth1.pid -lf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-e84c827b-0ae8-4305-8fb3-6aac18d1616a-eth1.lease -cf /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-eth1.conf eth1
cielaq    2349  2278  0 23:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dhcp

Comment: That's not it.  That's your client running.  So, dhcp server isn't the issue.