# Broadcom 4313 on ubuntu 12.04 have some problem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, broadcom

i have lenovo z58 laptop and i have installed ubuntu 12.04

The wifi hardware is Broadcom and reading on-line hi have resolved the problem about driver

Now the wifi works. The problem is that when my laptop has been connected to wifi, the other devices have a big problem with surfing.

Can someone help me?

EDIT:

```
    giovanni@giovanni-Lenovo-Z580:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 08:9e:01:31:30:08
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth2
       version: 01
       serial: c0:14:3d:c9:54:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) ip=192.168.1.65 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:18 memory:f0500000-f0503fff
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: sudo lshw -C network

Comment: I have edited the post :D

Comment: I suggest you try an earlier version of the driver as here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360447/why-my-roommates-connection-to-the-internet-is-lost-when-im-connected-to-our/

Comment: Do this procedure works fine in 12.04?

Comment: It depends on what kernel version you have. There are several 12.04 versions; 12.04, 12.04.2, 12.04.3, etc. What is your kernel? From the terminal: uname -r

Comment: 3.8.0-37-generic

Comment: I don't have that exact kernel version here, but I am pretty confident it will work. If not, it is easy enough to remove .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my netbook in 12.04.  You want the proprietary firmware so first you should install linux-firmware-nonfree.

But there is more than one adapter called broadcom 4313.  You'll need the pci id.  Enter in terminal:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

Mine is 14e4:4727 (rev 01), and I don't feel qualified to guarantee this would work for others but it worked for me:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2132918&p=12594170#post12594170

I've run 12.04, 13.04 and now 13.10 on my netbook with the 4313/4727 adapter and used a backport every time, but it's been getting better with every new release.  I ran it for some time in 13.10 with just the firmware install and didn't realize I should use a backport for a while.

Eagerly awaiting the 14.04 lts ... 12.04 just doesn't work as well on this netbook, which also has the cedarview gpu.  Hopefully I won't need a backport next time ...