# When I connect to the Wi-Fi, every other host in the "near" subnets cannot use the Internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've been experiencing the following problem recently.

When I connect to the Wi-Fi network of the router `A`, the Internet connection speed of every other host in that network slows down to 0.1-02 Mbps,
while my connection works properly - 20-25 Mbps. 
Then I connect to the router `B` which is a little far from `A`, then the all hosts *(but me)* of both `A` and `B` experience the same problem.

I guess there are some problems related to wireless interference, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to fix it.

P.S: When I switch to Windows 7, everything works properly.

EDIT:

Details of the wireless device:

Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: Done. It is "Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)"

Comment: Please check here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/360447/why-my-roommates-connection-to-the-internet-is-lost-when-im-connected-to-our/

Comment: İ checked your solution and the situation is reversed. Now I can't connect to the Internet while others do well. Please let me know what should I do now )

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try the other available driver for your device. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
echo "blacklist b43"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe brcmsmac
exit
```

It may take a reboot.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Can you please explain what was the problem?

Comment: I believe the Broadcom STA driver is incorrect for your 14e4:4727 device. We removed it and activated the native brcmsmac driver.

Answer (score 0):

Are both routers using the same channel, or close? As a rule, close wireless networks should be separated by at least 2 channels (or more, if you don't interfere with other networks in the area).

Comment: I don't know if they use the same channel. The first route is in my house, but the another one is in the neighborhood. The problem is that when my computer doesn't connect to one of them, or when I connect by using Windows 7, there's no such problem. I mean every other hosts in those networks can use the Internet properly in that case.