# 13.10 BCM4313 network problems after update

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

I have a problem with my network adapter after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10. The adapter works for literally several seconds after I establish the connection but then it looks as if it got clogged somehow.

This is what I see amongst my devices:

```
~$ lspci | grep -i wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
~$ uname -a
Linux bubek 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:12:00 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
~$ lsmod | grep 80211
lib80211_crypt_tkip    17387  0 
lib80211               14040  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
cfg80211              401436  1 wl
```

Now, how does is behave. Let's assume I connect to my wireless network and straight after I get connected I ping the default gw:

```
~$ ping 10.1.0.1
PING 10.1.0.1 (10.1.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=226 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=222 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=260 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=11 ttl=64 time=265 ms
64 bytes from 10.1.0.1: icmp_seq=16 ttl=64 time=117 ms
From 10.1.0.16 icmp_seq=45 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.1.0.16 icmp_seq=46 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What has happened over here? Is there any possibility I can get it working? The only way I could write that post was that I used my phone and USB tethering :)

Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -rv wl
sudo modprobe -v brcmsmac
```

if there are any errors please continue with the commands then reboot. your wireless should be working now.

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problems with BCM4313 wireless on an Asus laptop after I updated it to Ubuntu 13.10 and the wireless stopped working with _some_ hotspots (newer ones, I assume, as it worked with an old wrt54).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check your current driver. You can do this by typing `sudo lshw > hw_info` in a terminal.

Scroll to *Wireless interface*. It should show your current driver and the version used.

```
        *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Broadcom Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
            logical name: eth1
            version: 01
            serial: ec:55:f9:2a:d3:58
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=5.100.82.112 ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            resources: irq:19 memory:d4000000-d4003fff
```

You can see from the last line, that I am using **wl0** driver version 5.100.82.112.

There are several drivers to choose from ([Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)). You can switch to **brcmsmac** or use the 5.100 version of **wl0** which has so far worked without any problems by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/346245/62612).

Comment: Also, you should probably report this as a bug in launchpad so that it can be fixed.