# Ubuntu 13.10 recognizes wifi networks but won't connect (BCM4313)

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, broadcom

So, I partitioned my hard driver and installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 in partition C:.

First I installed Windows and got the wifi device working by installing the proper drivers for Broadcom BCM4313.

Then, after installing and while loged in Ubuntu 13.10, it recognizes my network and asks for the password, but won't connect.

Also I tried this https://askubuntu.com/a/368467/176713 and despite the fact that I don't know what it means, Terminal didn't recognize the second command line as well.

Please, send help.
And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: My BCM4313 uses the one of the right drivers - mine shows as `bcma-pci-bridge` (the `bcma` module). It is used by `b43` and `brcmsmac`. Either run `lsmod` and search for `bcma`, or run `lsmod | grep bcma` and see if that has any output. Those commands in 'http://askubuntu.com/a/368467/176713' I think should work, you just need to try them a few more times.

Comment: N.B. You may need to setup a proxy manually on Ubuntu, as Windows sometimes does that automatically, while Ubuntu does not...

Comment: You're right! It worked by trying these command lines a few more times. Thank you.