# HP G72 Ubuntu 12.10 - Wireless Broken

Tags: wireless, networking

I've had this HP G72 notebook for about a year now. Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on it. (12.04, but it installed 12.10) When I had the install disc in the computer when I clicked try Ubuntu and whilst it was installing, the WiFi worked fine. Now that I don't have the disc in, it doesn't even show any networks to connect to. I've tried looking around for fixes but everything is for older Ubuntu versions and don't seem to work.

Output of `lspci | grep -i Network`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: Edit the question and add the output of running `lspci | grep -i Network`

Comment: I've added the output of that. (Took me a minute to figure out how to put the line on the question)

Comment: Your Ubuntu is 64-bit or 32-bit? (Open System Settings and click on "Details", there you will see _os-type_ and version of Ubuntu.)

Comment: It's 64-Bit. The Win 7 that came with it was as well.

Comment: Can you connect to the Internet via a wired connection? (I know you cannot activate the wireless, but do you have a wired connection available?)

Comment: Yes, I am currently using a wired connection, tethering to my desktop. Would work the same way with any Ethernet.

Comment: OK, that makes things easier I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This question has an answer in

[Broadcom Corp. BCM4313 Wirelss not detected in Ubuntu 12.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/265886/159545)

---

Since you have a wired connection that makes things easier. Open a terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Reboot and then try setting up the wireless.

(You can also use the Software Center and search for "b43 firmware".)

Comment: This is the whole output of that

http://pastebin.com/GedTJKLg

Comment: @Sharkie Try this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/265886/159545)

Comment: That one worked great! I'm not sure the proper way to credit you for help on this site is, but thank you.

Comment: @Sharkie Being able to help you is satisfaction enough :) You can also upvote the question/answer I linked to. (Now I am going to mark this question as a duplicate.)