# Making Broadcom BCM4313 driver gives error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’

Tags: broadcom, make

I’m trying to build a driver for my bcm4313 wireless network adapter using these [instructions from broadcom](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt).

I'm getting this error:

```
KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
CFG80211 API is prefered for this kernel version
Using CFG80211 API
  CC [M]  /home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_tkip_printstats’:
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3246:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘wl->tkipmodops->print_stats’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
       wl->tkip_bcast_data[idx]);
       ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3246:7: note: expected ‘struct seq_file *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3249:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘wl->tkipmodops->print_stats’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
    wl->tkipmodops->print_stats(debug_buf, wl->tkip_ucast_data);
    ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3249:4: note: expected ‘struct seq_file *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: In function ‘wl_reg_proc_entry’:
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3470:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  if ((wl->proc_entry = create_proc_entry(tmp, 0644, NULL)) == NULL) {
  ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3470:22: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  if ((wl->proc_entry = create_proc_entry(tmp, 0644, NULL)) == NULL) {
                      ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3475:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->read_proc = wl_proc_read;
                ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3476:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->write_proc = wl_proc_write;
                ^
/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:3477:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  wl->proc_entry->data = wl;
                ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/keroles/hybrid_wl/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/keroles/hybrid_wl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-15-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't know why, any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to build them yourself. Please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/265886/159545).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am using BCM4313 driver and I am writing this via wifi connected internet. All I did to get it worked is to install Additional Drivers which founds in Software & Updates. It installs STA driver for me. Sure you need to connect internet via ethernet cable.

Have a nice day and I'm here to help you again.

Comment: Well actually i have more of performance issues with the driver...like when i'm using windows on the same laptop or my android phone it works very good on my home network, but with this driver it keeps disconnecting and asking for password several times till it disconnect again